# Uploading multiple pictures from android gallery to php server using multipart entity

Tags: android, image, gallery

I am following below tutorial for uploading multiple images into server.

http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/01/upload-multiple-image-using-webservice.html

But every time i upload, the app is uploading data multiple times along with pictures.

i.e: If i select 5 pictures from gallery and i'm sending "hello", "world" parameters along with 5 pics,

The app is uploading 5 pics correctly but "hello" and "world" parameters are uploaded for 5 times.

Please give a solution for this problem.

Comment: Show the relevant code you use now. We will not dive into that link. You could also explain why the words are send with every file now. How does that happen?

Comment: You should also show the server code that can handle more images at once.